# I am not able to connect to the database for any task in SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012

I am new to SSIS and installed the Datatool and sql server enterprise edition. When I try to connect to sql server it is not showing the database and table names .

Comment: Please post more info, like how you are trying to connect, and a screenshot of what's happening.

Comment: Hi Vibhuti Not sure if its an access issue. Could you please include some screenshots? That should help people come with better solutions.